# 'User Templates' not showing up in 'New Project' window - Xcode 4

Tags: templates, sdl, xcode4

I recently downloaded two SDL packages from the SDL website and moved them to the appropriate folders. in :/Library/Application Support/Developer/Shared/Xcode/Project Templates, I made a folder called "Applications" and in it I moved 'SDL Application' and two other SDL folders. Also, in: /Library/Frameworks, I moved SDL.Framework. When I make a new project, I see in the left side bar a section for iOS and Mac OS X. But what I want is a 'User templates' section, but it isn't there. 
(I would post a picture, but apparently I need 10 rep points to do so)
I thought there should automatically be a 'User Templates' bar in between iOS and MacOS X. I want to choose a new project that is pre-loaded with OpenGL and SDL. Is there a preferences setting that needs to be changed?
Thanks in advance!  (and sorry if its a stupid question :-P)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The template rules have changed in between XCode 3.x and XCode 4. As such any XCode 3 templates no longer work. You will have to wait for new ones to be added.

For now you will have to create your own project and add in the libraries yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Nitobi is providing a [web service](https://build.phonegap.com/generate) to generate Xcode templates for PhoneGap-based projects. (From: http://blogs.nitobi.com/shazron/2011/03/16/creating-a-phonegap-project-from-the-command-line-for-xcode-4/)