# How to set up SDL on XCODE 4?

Tags: xcode, xcode4, sdl

I'm having troubles with sample templates and overall installing of SDL on my Xcode 4.
There are no tutorials and old templates just don't work!
If anybody has Xcode 4 SDL templates, please share.

EDIT:
@Joshua Nozzi I tried opening template from old version of XCODE, 3.2 and it opened, but there were no files in the project and it said - base sdk missing. I tried adding SDL.framework but it didn't help!

Comment: What have you tried? How does it not work? What errors are you encountering? *Help us help you.*

Comment: Xcode 4 only includes the 10.6 SDK, and the templates included with SDL were probably configured to use an older one. Why would you expect adding the SDL.framework to help, with the error message didn't say anything about a missing framework?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5370254/user-templates-not-showing-up-in-new-project-window-xcode-4 and "[Xcode 4 and SDL Templates](http://elysianshadows.com/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=5871)."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I just pushed my working SDL test Xcode project as a public Github repository, so feel free to see if it works for you: https://github.com/Ricket/HelloSDL

Comment: It works like a charm. Where did you find a good (and working) Xcode 4 Template for SDL ? (setting up an SDL application via XCode is such a pain)

Comment: @Rootosaurus I started with the XCode project that comes with SDL and then fixed its problems, that's all.

Comment: This helped me a lot too, thanks!

To show my appreciation I thought I'd share the modifications I've made to it for my own purposes, so my fork of it can be found here: https://github.com/thoughton/HelloSDL-tlh

In a nutshell the differences are that it links with a locally built SDL 1.3 dylib (instead of a Framework), and it copies the dylib into the app bundle and makes the necessary install_name modifications so the app is distributable and relocatable (in a nice automated fashion).

More info can be found in the readme on its GitHub page.