# How to set Xcode frameworks search paths?

Tags: c++, xcode, sdl

I am trying to open a screen with an image saying hello. It shows no errors on Xcode, but when I run the program, the screen pops up black. It is just a black screen, and doesnt show the image saying hello. I heard that the solution is to put the image into the same directory, so I dragged it onto Xcode. Still, it shows up black.

```
   #include "SDL/SDL.h"

   int main( int argc, char* args[] )
 {
//The images
SDL_Surface* hello = NULL;
SDL_Surface* screen = NULL;

//Start SDL
SDL_Init( SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING );

//Set up screen
screen = SDL_SetVideoMode( 640, 480, 32, SDL_SWSURFACE );

//Load image
hello = SDL_LoadBMP( "hello.bmp" );

//Apply image to screen
SDL_BlitSurface( hello, NULL, screen, NULL );

//Update Screen
SDL_Flip( screen );

//Pause
SDL_Delay( 2000 );

//Free the loaded image
SDL_FreeSurface( hello );

//Quit SDL
SDL_Quit();

return 0;
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to set up SDL on XCODE 4?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5756540/how-to-set-up-sdl-on-xcode-4)

Answer (score 1):

the problem is that the image isn't in the same place once the executable starts running.

You might be able to get around this problem in the short term by changing the "custom working directory"
[image: Custom Working Directory]
<sub>(source: [nathdaly at www-personal.umich.edu](http://www-personal.umich.edu/%7Enathdaly/XcodeEditor.png))</sub>

found under the top menu in "Product->Edit Scheme..."

This is a good quick fix to see if you can get the program working.
But this won't work for an application you actually want to release.

To do that, you need to embed the images into your game so that they will "ship" with the package. Add the images into your Xcode Project, like you have done, and then be sure they are included in the "Copy Bundle Resources" build Phase under the "Build Phases" tab when you click on the Target.

Answer (score 0):

Go to your project's settings and click on "Build Settings". From there, you can type "framework" into the filter field at the top of the build settings, and it will show you several settings related to frameworks. In the section marked "Search Paths" is "Framework Search Paths". You can add new paths there.

To learn more, go to the "Help" menu, choose "Xcode Help" and type "Framework search path" in the search box of the Help window.

Comment: hello, I tried using the help, but didn't find anything. I found the frameworks search path, but doing #include <sdl/sdl.h> is still not working. Maybe I added it wrong? I really need help :/

Comment: How is SDL built? Do you have an SDL.framework? Or is it a static library? Or is it just code you include in your project?